# Converting a JSON object into JS array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

This is what I get as a jQuery response from Wordpress database after `json_encode`:

```
[{ "id" : "33", "first_name" : "Oleg", "last_name" : "Smith" }]
```

Because it is multi-dimensional in nature, but there is just one row, hence you have square brackets on both ends.

Therefore ALL methods I found on SO when trying to parse and then convert to a JS array fail, e.g.

```
for(var x in parsed){
    arr.push(parsed[x]);
}
```

OR

```
var arr = $.map(obj, function(el) { return el; });
```

OR

```
var arr = Object.keys(obj).map(function(k) { return obj[k] });
```

OR

```
for(var i in JsonObj) {
    if(JsonObj.hasOwnProperty(i) && !isNaN(+i)) {
        array[+i] = JsonObj[i];
    }
}
```

I can manually remove square brackets and proceed OR I can push manually each item:

```
aaData.push(searchObj[0].first_name);
```

But I don't like either of the solutions I have. Do I have other options?

PS. I need a JS array so that I can loop through with `[i]`.

Comment: After you parse and try to convert to a JS array it is stil an object, not an array. I tried many times, it only works when you remove square brackets.

Comment: @vegan-sv, do you want to loop through values? That is, you want to push values 33,Oleg,Smoth to aaData?

Comment: @VitaliyTsvayer yes. I can push manually, but I don't like it.

Comment: I'm confused - are you trying to loop through this object: `{ "id" : "33", "first_name" : "Oleg", "last_name" : "Smith" }`. If so, can't you access the object as `response[0]` and then use a `for in` loop?

Comment: I mean I don't want to loop like this searchObj[0].first_name, I want to loop like this searchObj [ i ] because it is just one row.

Comment: So you want to loop through an array of one element?

Comment: @vegan-sv, if I undestood you correctly have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following to push all values to aaData array:

```
var parsed = [{ "id" : "33", "first_name" : "Oleg", "last_name" : "Smith" }];
var aaData = [];
for(key in parsed[0]) { aaData.push(parsed[0][key]); }
```

So, now you have "33", "Oleg", "Smith" in aaData, which you can access by index:

```
aaData[0] will give you 33
aaData[1] will give you Oleg, etc
```

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to be able to handle the case where there is more than one element in the searchObj array. In that case you can loop through all elements of the array and push each of them:

```
for (var i = 0; i < searchObj.length; i++) {
    aaData.push(searchObj[i].first_name);
}
```

When there is only one element, only that one element will be pushed.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the JSON and then loop through the data, inserting each item into your collection array like such:

```
var parsedData = JSON.parse(responseData);

parsedData.forEach(function (item) {
    arrayCollection.push(item);
}
```

This one will work on older browsers too:

```
var parsedData = $.parseJSON(responseData);

$.each(parsedData, function (index, item) {
    arrayCollection.push(item);
}
```